# Was Array.prototype.sort.call() ever supposed to return the window object?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I have been toying around with obfuscating Javascript with just brackets and other symbols, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910353/obfuscated-javascript-code-with-binary-values) and [this automatic  generator](http://discogscounter.getfreehosting.co.uk/js-noalnum.php) - for purely educational reasons, may I say :)

For example, evaluating `(![]+[])[+!+[]]` gives me the letter `"a"`.

However, it seems that the examples rely on `[].sort.call()` returning the window object. My problem is that whenever this doesn't seem to work on any of the browsers I have installed (Chrome 14, FF 9, IE 9):

```js
//They told me this would return the window object
[].sort.call() 

//But I get an exception instead:
"TypeError: Array.prototype.sort called on null or undefined"
```

**So I ask:**

- Was `[].sort.call()` fixed on recent browsers or does it still return the window object and its just me doing something wrong?
- If it is the case that I can't use this approach anymore, are there any other ways I can access the window object using only brackets, parenthesis, exclamation marks and the + operators?

Comment: What code gives you `"TypeError: Array.prototype.sort called on null or undefined"` ?

Comment: @Sarfraz: `[].sort.call()` gives the error. I wanted it to return the window object instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was changed with ECMAScript 5. From [15.3.4.4](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4):

> **NOTE** The thisArg value is passed without modification as the **this** value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a **undefined** or **null** thisArg is replaced with the **global object** and **ToObject** is applied to all other values and that result is passed as the **this** value.

...and [`sort()`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11) calls [`ToObject`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.9) on that **this** value, throwing the `TypeError` exception.

And, given the addition of [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode), which [further reduces access to the global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript), your options are probably few. Though, without `"use strict"`, you might try using `this`.

Comment: Using `this` looks less cool then just a bunch of brackets though :(. But it looks like there is no alternative, since we can't think of ways to get the window from either properties or method calls of regular objects, arrays or numbers...

Comment: Actually, I think i found an alternative. `[]['filter']['constructor']` is not hard to get to and gives us eval-like powers. From there its not hard to get whateverI want (although it might get a bit long)

Comment: @hugomg - Alternatively `""["sub"]["constructor"]` or `[]["pop"]["constructor"]`